# msf4j JWTAccessTokenBuilder threws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: wso2-msf4j, wso2-identity-server

I am running wso2is Version 5.7 and tried to implement a TokenGenerator based on msf4j JWTAccessTokenBuilder.

My identity.xml includes

> <IdentityOAuthTokenGenerator>com.wso2.jwt.token.builder.JWTAccessTokenBuilder</IdentityOAuthTokenGenerator>
>         <AccessTokenValueGenerator>org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.tokenvaluegenerator.SHA256Generator</AccessTokenValueGenerator>

When I login an exception is thrown

> [2019-05-16 18:27:18,163] ERROR
>   {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [OAuth2Endpoints] in context with path [/oauth2] threw
>   exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault:
>   com/nimbusds/jwt/ReadOnlyJWTClaimsSet
>           at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
>           at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:336)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
>          ...
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault:
>   com/nimbusds/jwt/ReadOnlyJWTClaimsSet
>           at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:170)
>           at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:136)
>           at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204)
>           at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
>           at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
>           at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
>           at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
>           ... 49 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nimbusds/jwt/ReadOnlyJWTClaimsSet
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
>            ...
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)
>           at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
>           ... 54 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nimbusds.jwt.ReadOnlyJWTClaimsSet cannot be found by
>   JWTAccessTokenBuilder_2.7.4.SNAPSHOT

Can anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:
I used an old version of org.wso2.carbon.identity.inbound.auth.oauth2
I updated the pom.xml to

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.inbound.auth.oauth2</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.172</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

from https://mvnrepository.com and had to update the code to use the version of com.nimbusds.jwt used by wso2is.
And finally in the service provider settings you must select the Token Issuer.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error `com.nimbusds.jwt.ReadOnlyJWTClaimsSet cannot be found by JWTAccessTokenBuilder_2.7.4.SNAPSHOT`, it is due to the OSGi class binding. 
In the maven-bundle-plugin configuration Import-Package of the pom, make sure you have the `com.nimbusds.jwt` with the correct version range.

Or the quick fix is to add `<DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>`